# 302 Redirect without Redirecting to Page (HTML)

Tags: html, redirect, http-status-code-302, weebly

I have an [old website](http://ericburnett.net) on Weebly that I would like to redirect (302) to my new WordPress site, [Endelve Design](http://endelvedesign.com). As far as I know, the only way I can perform a 302 redirect with Weebly is by adding code to the header pages, so I am limited to using HTML and JavaScript. However, I would like to redirect pages like so:

```
http://ericburnett.net -> http://endelvedesign.com
http://ericburnett.net/blog.html -> http://endelvedesign.com
```

Essentially, I would like to redirect *all* pages in my old site to the home page of my new site. I do not want it to do this:

```
http://ericburnett.net/blog.html -> http://endelvedesign.com/blog.html
```

I find that if I use any of the following methods, it produces the undesired results seen above.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://endelvedesign.com" />
<script type="text/javascript"> window.location="http://endelvedesign.com"; </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this question more suited for the other boards like [server fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @HristoValkanov I thought this was more of a coding question since I can only use HTML and JavaScript; I can't access cPanel, Apache, or anything like that. Weebly does not allow server access. Sorry if this is still in the wrong place--I can move it if it really shouldn't be here.

Comment: I have the same problem.  There doesn't seem to be a way to do either a 302 or a 301 redirect FROM a free weebly site TO another domain. It's possible that you can do this with one of their paid options.  I tried to enter a meta refresh tag into Settings->SEO->header but it had no effect.  You should be able to use javascript in the page to do the redirection but I don't think search engines will pick up on that and your new site won't benefit from the ranking of your old site.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response. This question is not for this board, because it's more administration, than programing. First of all you need to know your way around the `.htaccess` file. In your case it's more than enough to know this line:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/.*$ http://endelvedesign.com/
```

It redirects all hits from your old site to your new site with code 301 (Permanent redirect).

The second part of your problem is accessing the file itself. I never used weebly, but after googling around for a while I found many solutions, ranging from praying to the moon gods while sacrificing sea water, to actually solving your problem by hand. There are 2 way which caught my eye.

1. The first one is via the SEO panel. In order to avoid the wall of text answer, i suggest you look for exact instructions [here](http://rajalpanchal.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/how-to-do-301-redirection-in-weebly-site/). If you are lazy to look at the link and/or good at managing on your own it in Setting->SEO->301 redirects. Judging by the tutorials it has some limitations.
2. The second method is to export/import your site. Basically you export your site, add the code above to the `.htaccess` file and you import the site back.

A friendly reminder: I never used weebly, so those resolutions are based on what I found on the subject, as in I never tested them.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but there doesn't seem to be a way to import a previously exported site into Weebly as described in your second method. I decided to have the domain redirect through my domain registrar, but it still redirects to the original page, producing a 404. I'll just live with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a bit of javascript in the body.

```js
<script>
window.location = "http://www.newurl.com";
</script>
```

This way you can redirect, but not set a 301 or 302 header.